# I want to build an MSI installer of a JavaFx application with Ant

Tags: java, javafx, ant, windows-installer

I have developed a JavaFx application and it runs well without any problem. Now I want to build an MSI installer from it and I have modified build.fxbuild and build.xml. I have installed WIX tools also. When I run build.xml as an ant build it says build successful, but some error occurs and the MSI is not generated.

### Error

```
Buildfile: D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\build.xml
setup-staging-area:
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\externalLibs
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\project
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\projectRefs
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\externalLibs
     [copy] Copying 1 file to D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\externalLibs
     [copy] Copying 1 file to D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\externalLibs
     [copy] Copying 1 file to D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\externalLibs
     [copy] Copying 1 file to D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\externalLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\project
     [copy] Copying 17 files to D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\project
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\projectRefs
do-compile:
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\build
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\build\src
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\build\libs
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\build\classes
     [copy] Copying 4 files to D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\build\libs
     [copy] Copying 17 files to D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\build\src
    [javac] Compiling 10 source files to D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\build\classes
     [copy] Copying 7 files to D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\build\classes
init-fx-tasks:
do-deploy:
     [copy] Copying 4 files to D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\dist\libs
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\build\build\classes\META-INF
Using base JDK at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre
Using base JDK at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre

Bundler MSI Installer skipped because of a configuration problem: Can not find WiX tools (light.exe, candle.exe).

  
Advice to fix:   Download WiX 3.0 or later from http://wix.sf.net and add it to the PATH.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 5 seconds
```

Above error occurs though I have included WIX into the environment path.

### build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project name="java fx" default="do-deploy" basedir="."  xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
    <target name="init-fx-tasks">
        <path id="fxant">
            <filelist>
                <file name="${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
                <file name="${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
            </filelist>
        </path>
    
        <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
            uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
            classpathref="fxant"/>
    </target>
    <target name="setup-staging-area">
        <delete dir="externalLibs" />
        <delete dir="project" />
        <delete dir="projectRefs" />
    
        <mkdir dir="externalLibs" />
    
        <copy todir="externalLibs">
            <fileset dir="D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\lib">
                <filename name="jfxrt.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="externalLibs">
            <fileset dir="D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\lib">
                <filename name="postgresql-42.2.5.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="externalLibs">
            <fileset dir="D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\lib">
                <filename name="mssql-jdbc-7.2.1.jre8.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="externalLibs">
            <fileset dir="D:\SmallExperiment\java fx\lib">
                <filename name="rt.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    
        <mkdir dir="project" />
        <copy todir="project">
            <fileset dir="D:\SmallExperiment\java fx">
                <include name="src/**" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    
        <mkdir dir="projectRefs" />
    </target>
    <target name='do-compile'>
        <delete dir="build" />
        <mkdir dir="build/src" />
        <mkdir dir="build/libs" />
        <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
    
        <!-- Copy project-libs references -->
        <copy todir="build/libs">
            <fileset dir="externalLibs">
                <include name="jfxrt.jar"/>
                <include name="postgresql-42.2.5.jar"/>
                <include name="mssql-jdbc-7.2.1.jre8.jar"/>
                <include name="rt.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    
        <!-- Copy project references -->
    
        <!-- Copy project sources itself -->
        <copy todir="build/src">
            <fileset dir="project/src">
                <include name="**/*"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    
        <javac includeantruntime="true" source="1.8" target="1.8" srcdir="build/src" destdir="build/classes" encoding="Cp1252">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="build/libs">
                    <include name="*"/>
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    
        <!-- Copy over none Java-Files -->
        <copy todir="build/classes">
        <fileset dir="project/src">
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
        </copy>
    
    
    </target>
    <target name="do-deploy" depends="setup-staging-area, do-compile, init-fx-tasks">
        <delete file="dist"/>
        <delete file="deploy" />
    
        <mkdir dir="dist" />
        <mkdir dir="dist/libs" />
    
        <copy todir="dist/libs">
            <fileset dir="externalLibs">
                <include name="*" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    
    
        <fx:resources id="appRes">
            <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="java fx.jar"/>
            <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*"/>
        </fx:resources>
    
        <fx:application id="fxApplication"
            name="ConfOfApp"
            mainClass="application.Main"
        />
    
        <mkdir dir="build/classes/META-INF" />
    
    
    
        <fx:jar destfile="dist/java fx.jar">
            <fx:application refid="fxApplication"/>
            <fileset dir="build/classes">
            </fileset>
            <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
    
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="com.ankur"/>
                <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="ConfOfApp"/>
                <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.0.2"/>
                <attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None"/>
            </manifest>
        </fx:jar>
    
    
        <mkdir dir="deploy" />
        <!-- Need to use ${basedir} because somehow the ant task is calculating the directory differently -->
        <fx:deploy
            embedJNLP="false"
            extension="false"
            includeDT="false"
            offlineAllowed="true"
            outdir="${basedir}/deploy"
            outfile="java fx" nativeBundles="msi"
            updatemode="background" >
    
            <fx:platform basedir="${java.home}"/>
            <fx:info title="java fx" vendor="com.ankur"/>
    
            <fx:application refId="fxApplication"/>
            <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
        </fx:deploy>
    
    
    </target>
</project>
```